# Creating paragraph layout

Tags: html, css

How to set two of paragraphs to the very left and two paragraphs to the very right-side? The paragraphs are nested in one div.

Here is what i done so far

```css
.advantages p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.advantages p:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  left: 550px;
  top: -20px;
}

.advantages p:nth-child(5) {
  position: relative;
  left: 550px;
  top: -20px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

</div>
```

Comment: look up how "position:relative", "float:left" and "float:right" work

Comment: @durbnpoisn well I was gonna post that, but you beat me to it. About the only other option is `display:inline-block;` and setting widths with some abs-pos magic.

Comment: It is rather unclear what exactly you are asking here. Please show any work you have already tried and what didnt work or what it is that you dont understand. Are you writing pure HTML? e.g. if you are using something like bootstrap then the solution may be different (i.e. using columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what you're going for in your code.

```
.advantages p {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    border: dashed 1px red;
}

.advantages p:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

One thing you were missing is setting the width of the paragraphs. Things will look a little goofy when the lines of text in a paragraph are different, but this is (an) answer to your question.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stgermaniac/wa1w319z/